# How to completely revert the changes done by lm-sensors?

Tags: lenovo, fan, overheating, lm-sensors

I installed lm-sensors couple of week ago, and accepted all the defaults. Soon i started to notice that my laptop (lenovo Ideapad 3 i7-10U) started to heat up more than usual. Also, even if i boot to windows it kept fan at low speed else before that my fan always ran higher in windows and it was normal. So my question is how to revert all the changes done by lm-sensors? i have already used autoremove, purged its data and also deleted etc/modules? Any help would be highly appreciated.

System is dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and windows 10 pro.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. There is no such version of Ubuntu as latest. Ubuntu only uses version numbers.

Comment: "latest" Ubuntu LTS is two years old, your hardware is likely newer than that. Try an HWE kernel or a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Regardless of version; you may well need to reinstall lm-sensors and use it to "restore" changes manually. Check in windows if you can see what setting is used there... then apply the same under Ubuntu, then possibly purge lm-sensors again.

Comment: @David "20.04.4" i meant this version

Comment: Simply installing lm-sensors shouldn't affect your system.  It doesn't control the fan or the temperature.  What commands did you run after installing it?

Comment: @rtaft only sensor-detect

Comment: Did you say yes to everything or just yes to the default items?  Did it detect anything?

Comment: @rtaft default items and in the end yes to write to modules

Comment: what is in the modules file?  I believe its `/etc/modules`

Comment: @rtaft there was just one line other than comments and i dont remember it exacty. Though i deleted it after reading another thread related to the same issue

Comment: I assume `coretemp`.  I doubt `sensors-detect` changed anything that would cause this.  If you ran `pwmconfig`, then you might have switched the mode your fan runs in, but generally laptops don't come with PWM for it to be this case.

Comment: @rtaft dunno, maybe reinstall the distro?

Comment: you could run off livecd and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @rtaft oh yeah, it's better to check it before

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of version;
you may well need to reinstall lm-sensors and use it to "restore" changes manually.

Check in windows if you can see what setting is used there...
then apply the same under Ubuntu.

Later possibly purge lm-sensors again.

*(no backup of settings mentioned, is it even possible?)*

---

*With GNU/Linux you have a situation similar to "freedom under responsibility"; many times the hardware and software come from different "sources", the latter quite often from an individual - who might have missed a detail[1] in functionality of the hardware.*

*Parts of the automation available under "supported" OS's might not be there; so this is up to the user to pay attention and adjust accordingly.

e.g. the actually useful range of a setting might be lesser.*

*[1] This might be a special feature that has not been documented "in public" - i.e. no "free" information available.*

Comment: i just installed it to check temp whenever i wanted to, i didn't know that it could cause such a problem.

Comment: i never change those settings not even in windows because not enough experience with that. I preferred ubuntu over window to avoid useless consumption of ram and background processes while programming and indeed it is much peaceful on linux but sigh now this problem!